# How to set adapter for spinner in alert dialog

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

i´m making Android app and i found a problem.
I have activity and i have to make alert dialog from it. That wokrs fine, but i need a spinner in that dialog too and i cant set up adapter properly. App crashes with NullPointer ex. 
Piece of Dialog xml with spinner:

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

And here is code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_list);
    MyListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    registerForContextMenu(MyListView);
    myList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(
            MainActivity.NUMBER_LIST);
    for (MyCallLog m : myList) {
        stringList.add(m.getNumber());
    }
    MyListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringList) {
    });
}
```

And Dialog code:

```
public void DialogData(final int DialogTyp) {
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);


    AlertDialog.Builder MyBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    MyBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    if (DialogTyp == 1) {

                    }

                    else if (DialogTyp == 2) {
                        stringList.remove(aktual);
                    }

                    MyListView.invalidateViews();
                    return;
                }
            });

    MyBuilder.setNegativeButton("Storno",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    return;
                }
            });

    if (DialogTyp != 2)
        MyBuilder.setView(layout);

    AlertDialog MyAlertDialog = MyBuilder.create();

    if (DialogTyp == 0)
        MyAlertDialog.setTitle("Nový záznam");
    else if (DialogTyp == 1) {
        addItemsOnSpinner();
        MyAlertDialog.setTitle("Editace záznamu");
        ((EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.cislo)).setText(myCallLog.getNumber());
        ((EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.delka)).setText(String.valueOf(myCallLog.getDuration()));
        ((EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.datum)).setText("25.2.2015");
        ((Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner)).setSelection(getSelectedOperator(myCallLog.getOperator()));
    } else if (DialogTyp == 2) {
        MyAlertDialog.setTitle("Smazání záznamu" + aktual);
        MyAlertDialog.setMessage("Opravdu chcete smazat vybraný záznam?");
    }

    MyAlertDialog.show();
}

public void editList(int pozition, String number, String date, String spinner){

}

public void addItemsOnSpinner() {


    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("O2");
    list.add("T_MOBILE");
    list.add("VODAFONE");
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

Here on the last line there should be error.
Where is the problem or what i have to do to set up it correctly?

Comment: Spinner in Alert dialog?(What exactly you want a list on AlertDialog or exactly Spinner?)

Answer (score 1):

`spinner` is null because you're trying to `findViewById` from your Activity, which is not the dialog layout. Instead pass the spinner you have retrieved here

```
((Spinner)layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner))
```

into your `public void addItemsOnSpinner() {...}` method.

Comment: huh, i knew that will be something like that. It´s working now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the Spinner from a different view, if the Spinner is inside the dialog then you should do:

```
AlertDialog MyAlertDialog = MyBuilder.create();
Spinner spinnerInsideDialog = (Spinner) MyAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

Comment: I knew that will be something like that but even when i did that i´m still recieving same error on the same line.

Comment: Now i have another problem.
I can see one of the values in that spinner but after i click on it i got this error Unable to add window — token null is not for an application.

Edit: my bad i´m bit tired i found explonation in another topic i just didn´t know how to use it.